# Concurrency thread group

Tags: jmeter

I am quite new to Jmeter and just started using it. I have this requirement of setting up 1000 concurrent users with Ramp up - 100 Users every 2 mins and keeping them in steady state for an hour. How should my thread configuration be like? I am using Concurrency thread group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you tried so far? I believe [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) is self-explanatory and provides a nice chart with the anticipated load.

If you need to add 100 users every 2 minutes and want to end up with 1000 users it means:

- 20 minutes of the ramp-up time
- 10 ramp-up steps
- followed by 60 minutes to hold the load

Just in case here is an example setup:

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter - Elements of Test Plan - Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group)
- [JMeter Ramp-Up - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-ramp-up-the-ultimate-guide)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitri. That was a great help. I guess my point of confusion was because the total duration went up to an hour and 20 minutes when I added  the ramp up time. But all good now.